# Avoiding overlapping OnNext calls in Rx when using SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have some code using Rx, called from multiple threads that does:

```
subject.OnNext(value); // where subject is Subject<T>
```

I want the values to be processed in the background, so my subscription is

```
subscription = subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).Subscribe(value =>
{
    // use value
});
```

I don't really care which threads handle values coming out of the Observable, as long as the work is put into the TaskPool and doesn't block the current thread. However, my use of 'value' inside my OnNext delegate is not thread safe. At the moment, if a lot of values are going through the Observable I'm getting overlapping calls to my OnNext handler.

I could just add a lock to my OnNext delegate, but that doesn't feel like the Rx way of doing things. What's the best way to make sure I only have one call to my OnNext handler at a time, when I have multiple threads calling `subject.OnNext(value);`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Using Subjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242970%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on MSDN

> By default, subjects do not perform any synchronization across
>   threads. [...] If, however, you want to
>   synchronize outgoing calls to observers using a scheduler, you can use
>   the Synchronize method to do so.

So you should, as Brandon says in the comments, synchronize the subject and hand that out to your producer threads. e.g.

```
var syncSubject = Subject.Synchronize(subject);

// syncSubject.OnNext(value) can be used from multiple threads

subscription = syncSubject.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subscribe(value =>
{
    // use value
});
```

Comment: The call to `Synchronize` should be before the call to `ObserveOn` otherwise you are violating the concurrency contract for `ObserveOn`.  But in reality if the use case is sharing a subject among several threads, the best solution is to synchronize the subject instead of synchronizing the subscribers to the subject:  `var syncSubject = Subject.Synchronize(syncSubject);`  Now hand `syncSubject` out to your producer threads and they can call `syncSubject.OnNext()` without causing problems with subscribers of the original subject.

Comment: @Brandon var syncSubject = Subject.Synchronize(syncSubject); ... you are using a variable before it is assigned, can you clarify this?

Comment: @Beachwalker that's a typo. It should be `subject` passed as argument to Synchronize as shown in the answer

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for the .Synchronize() extension method. To get performance improvements in a recent release (late 2011) they Rx team relaxed the assumptions about the sequential nature of observable sequence producers. However it seems you break these assumptions (not a bad thing) but to get Rx back playing as users would expect, you should Synchronize the sequence to ensure it is sequential again.

Answer (score 2):

Here a bit more explanation why to use [Synchronize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242970%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (the second paragraph).
From the other side Synchronize may take part in deadlock if you actively use locking in your code, at least I witnessed such situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement your own IObserver which will apply a lock in its OnNext method. Just a simple decorator: apply a lock, call inner OnNext, remove the lock.

Then you can implement an extension method on IObservable, something like .AsThreadSafe().

Comment: Not best solution but no need to be downvoted from my point of view because it is a valid solution. So +1 from me to balance this a bit with the downvotes here.